# PHP 2 ASP cross domain script translation

Tags: php, asp-classic

I need to call via Ajax a routine on my PHP server from my clients site on his server. If my client has PHP, I have a short PHP script used to call a PHP from one server to another and avoid cross-scripting issues using CURL:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];   
$q=str_replace(" ","^",$q);   
$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/search2A.php?q=".$q);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);    
curl_exec($ch);    
curl_close($ch);    
?>
```

The problem are the clients with ASP sites, so this routine won't work and I have No idea how this would translate in ASP, so ASP does not run into a cross-browser issue. Any help, please?!!!

Regards,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%

Dim q
q = Replace(Request("q")," ","^")

Dim httpObject
Set httpObject = Server.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

httpObject.Open "GET", "http://myserver.com/search2A.php?q=" & q
httpObject.Send

Set httpObject = Nothing

%>
```